# Segmentation fault: 11 during bcftools merge

Tags: bash, bcftools

I am using bcftools to merge two vcf files. File 1 is 590MB with 4,732,099 unique variants. File 2 is 704MB with 1,774,673 unique variants. The files have some overlapping variants and are from entirely different samples. Ideally I want to merge them as they are without taking an intersection.

When I simply merge these files with `bcftools merge -o output.vcf file1.vcf.gz file2.vcf.gz` it works.

When I left align and split these variants though prior to the merge I get a rather cryptic `Segmentation fault: 11`.

The left alignment, normalisation and splitting is achieved with:

```
bcftools norm -m -both -f reference.fa.gz file1.vcf.gz -o file1.norm.vcf.gz
```

The output for each file looks like:

```
Lines   total/split/realigned/skipped:  4732099/310967/86666/0
Lines   total/split/realigned/skipped:  1774673/105052/119007/0
```

I see that a bug was reported previously in bcftools which resulted in a segmentation fault associated with working with 1000s of files. To investigate whether the file size was important I tried to merge file1.vcf with a large 1000 genomes vcf file. This fails with the same segmentation fault so I wonder if this is the issue. I'm not sure how I would go about working out which part of the system setup is insufficient.

If I run the same on a jupyter notebook I get a little more detail:

```
bash: line 1: 14238 Segmentation fault: 11  bcftools merge broad.norm.vcf.gz decode.norm.vcf.gz > case.vcf.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', 'bcftools merge broad.norm.vcf.gz  decode.norm.vcf.gz > case.vcf.gz\n')

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2478, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2476 with self.builtin_trap:
   2477     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2478     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2480 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2481 # when using magics with decodator @output_can_be_silenced
   2482 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2483 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py:154, in ScriptMagics._make_script_magic.<locals>.named_script_magic(line, cell)
    152 else:
    153     line = script
--> 154 return self.shebang(line, cell)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py:314, in ScriptMagics.shebang(self, line, cell)
    309 if args.raise_error and p.returncode != 0:
    310     # If we get here and p.returncode is still None, we must have
    311     # killed it but not yet seen its return code. We don't wait for it,
    312     # in case it's stuck in uninterruptible sleep. -9 = SIGKILL
    313     rc = p.returncode or -9
--> 314     raise CalledProcessError(rc, cell)

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'bcftools merge broad.norm.vcf.gz  decode.norm.vcf.gz > case.vcf.gz\n'' returned non-zero exit status 139.
```

Potentially in keeping with it being a size based issue if I take only the first 1000 normalised variants they merge fine (though I guess there could be odd variants later in the file that are causing the issues).

I'm working on an M2 mac with 32GB unified memory.

`ulimit -a`:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8176
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 5333
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Can anyone provide advice on how I could troubleshoot further and hopefully merge these vcf files?

Thanks,
Angus

Comment: This isn't at all a bash problem -- bash only controls the target program's startup, not its ongoing operation.

Comment: The details you _need_ to make this solvable are ones you'd get by compiling bcftools with debug symbols and using a debugger (traditionally gdb) to get a stack trace when it crashes. In practice, I'd look into whether there are any bug reports made to the bcftools team. Note that you need a stack trace _from bcftools itself_, not from the Python program you're using to run it.

Comment: (BTW, this is arguably right now not really defined in a way that makes it a software development question: Someone who wasn't a developer at all manually starting bcftools at the command line could hit the same problem; the problem isn't distinct or unique to people doing software development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the `bcftools` programs from sources, as close to the version that you are using. Then try to reproduce the problem, namely that this crashes:

```
bcftools merge broad.norm.vcf.gz  decode.norm.vcf.gz
```

If it reproduces, then try it with the latest code instead, in case it's something that was fixed.

Otherwise, drill into it, for instance with the GNU debugger:

```
gdb --args ./bcftools merge broad.norm.vcf.gz  decode.norm.vcf.gz
```

The tool works with compressed and uncompressed files of the files. If the problem reproduces with only the `.gz` files but not plain files, it's something with the decompression.

According to the issues database on GitHub, a crash was fixed in the merge feature just two days ago:

https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/1990

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. Using the very latest code has fixed the error, which it turns out was nothing to do with file size. Much appreciated - I've spent ages trying different things. I'll have a look at GNU debugger for future problems.